# Chunked encoding and content-length header

Tags: http, encoding, transfer, chunked

Is it possible to set the content-length header and also use chunked transfer encoding? and does doing so solve the problem of not knowing the length of the response at the client side when using chunked?

the scenario I'm thinking about is when you have a large file to transfer and there's no problem in determining its size, but it's too large to be buffered completely.
(If you're not using chunked, then the whole response must get buffered first? Right??)

thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. ***No***:

> "Messages MUST NOT include both a Content-Length header field and a non-identity transfer-coding. If the message does include a non-identity transfer-coding, the Content-Length MUST be ignored." ([RFC 2616, Section 4.4](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.4.4))

2. And ***no***, you *can* use Content-Length and stream; the protocol doesn't constrain how your implementation works.

Comment: I hope chunked transfer encoding is an example for stream; you have mentioned here ins't it? it may also include range requests. am i right?

Answer (score 14):

Well, you can always send a header stating the size of the file. 
Something like `response.addHeader("File-Size","size of the file");`
And ignore the Content-Length header.
The client implementation has to be tweaked to read this value, but hey you can achieve both the things you want :)

Comment: The convention is to use an `X-` prefix on any nonstandard header. A HTTP proxy may well decide to drop your non-standard non-X header.

Comment: Thanks MSalters, just got referenced to a similar guideline elsewhere, appreciate it.

Comment: As of 5 years ago, the `X-` prefix on nonstandard headers is frowned upon, deprecated, and not considered a best practice.  Just go ahead and use `file-size` as the header name, it's fine. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either Content-Length or chunking, but not both.

If you know the length in advance, you can use Content-Length instead of chunking even if you generate the content on the fly and never have it all at once in your buffer.

However, you should not do that if the data is really large because a proxy might not be able to handle it. For large data, chunking is safer.

Comment: Unfortunately not helpful if you need to download a large file with progress information.

Comment: The spec only says Content-Length is to be ignored if Transfer-Encoding is present, it doesn't say you can't send it, Base on experimenting with chrome, chrome will treat Content-Length as a hint if present, and display a progress bar for file downloads. If I send an incorrect content length that is too small it displays the progress bar until the download exceeds the indicated length then switches to the streaming progress bar, and still completes the download correctly.

Comment: This also worked when I set the Content-Length to be too large, the download stoped as per the rules for Chunking. Based on this I would use chunking for large files and set the Content-Length anyway, the only case it may be a problem is if the client is not standard compliant and give Content-Length precedences over Transfer-Encoding, hence I assume it shouldn't be a problem with any major web browsers (base on usage statistics) IE may be a problem but from memory its only about 2% of web users these days so I don't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

This headers can be cause of Postman Parse Error:

> "Content-Length" and "Transfer-Encoding" can't be present in the response headers together.

Using parametrized `ResponseEntity<?>` except raw `ResponseEntity` in controller can fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks:

> **Is it possible** to set the content-length header and also use chunked transfer encoding?

The [RFC `HTTP/1.1` spec](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.4.4), quoted in [Julian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304186/5134722), says:

> Messages **MUST NOT** include both a Content-Length header field and a non-identity transfer-coding.

There is an important difference between what's possible, and what's allowed by a protocol. It is certainly possible, for example, for you to write your own `HTTP/1.1` client which sends malformed messages with both headers. You would be violating the `HTTP/1.1` spec in doing so, and so you'd imagine some alarm bells would go off and a bunch of Internet police would burst into your house and say, "Stop, arrest that client!" But that doesn't happen, of course. Your request will get sent to wherever it's going.

OK, so you can send a malformed message. So what? Surely on the receiving end, the server will detect the `HTTP/1.1` protocol client-side violation, vanquish your malformed request, and serve you back a stern 400 response telling you that you are due in court the following Monday for violating the protocol. But no, actually, that probably won't happen. Of course, it's beyond the scope of `HTTP/1.1` to prescribe what happens to misbehaving clients; i.e. while the `HTTP/1.1` protocol is analogous to the "law", there is nothing in `HTTP/1.1` analogous to the judicial system.

The best that the `HTTP/1.1` protocol can do is dictate how a server must act/respond in the case of receiving such a malformed request. However, it's quite lenient in this case. In particular, the server does not have to reject such malformed requests. In fact, in such a scenario, the rule is:

> If the message does include a non-identity transfer-coding, the Content-Length MUST be ignored.

Unfortunately, though, some HTTP servers will violate that part of the `HTTP/1.1` protocol and will actually give precedence to the `Content-Length` header, if both headers are present. This can cause a serious problem, if the message visits two servers in sequence in the same system and they disagree about where one HTTP message ends and the next one starts. It leaves the system vulnerable to [HTTP Desync attacks](https://portswigger.net/research/http-desync-attacks-request-smuggling-reborn) a.k.a. [Request Smuggling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_request_smuggling).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question was about http responses, not http requests, but either way nodejs rejects them if Content-Length is combined with Transfer-Encoding... if both are present in a request nodejs responds with `400 Bad Request`, if both are present in a response the ClientRequest fails with `Parse Error: Content-Length can't be present with Transfer-Encoding`