# Transferring large files: combining streamed transfer and content-length

Tags: c#, wcf, http, browser, http-headers

TL;DR: How can I stream large files with a known size using WCF, and still show progress (`Content-Length`) to the final user (a web browser)?

I have a WCF REST service which downloads and then serves very large files (1-20Gb) to a web browser. To simplify, think of my service as a proxy. This obliges me to set `TransferMode = Streamed` or `TransferMode = StreamedResponse` on the Binding, or the end client will have to wait for the source files to be downloaded to the webserver before the actual download begins. Also, buffered transfer mode kills the server for large files (RAM usage). Intermediate disk storage is not an option. From [TransferMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding.TransferMode%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) man page:

> [(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding.TransferMode%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)  Buffered transfers hold the entire message in a memory buffer until
>   the transfer is complete.

But when setting `TransferMode` to `Streamed` or `StreamedResponse`, WCF no longer returns the header `Content-length` to the client, and a new header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is added. This is consistent with [wikipedias article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) on chunked transfer:

> (...) uses the Transfer-Encoding HTTP header *in place* of the Content-Length
>   header (...)

But I always know the size of the data to be transferred beforehand, and for the end user, it's very frustrating not to know the size of the download. So:

(How) can I configure the WCF binding to use a "streaming" Transfer mode (more specifically, *not* buffering the entire message before sending) and still use the `Content-Length` header?

Some leads:

- [This q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304126/chunked-encoding-and-content-length-header) states that the http standard disallows both `Transfer-Encoding` and `Content-length: 123456` in the same message, so I guess that's not an option?
- I have tried modifying the headers using an inspector in [IDispatchMessage.BeforeSendReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but at this point the `Content-Length` header has not yet been removed, and `Transfer-Encoding` has not yet been set, so it's "too early". I have later read that chunked transfer encoding is on TCP level, so changing the header at this point probably wont work even if I could.
- I have tried setting [aspNetCompatibilityEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.aspnetcompatibilityenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`="true"`, setting wcf transfer mode to buffered output (default) and then set `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;`. This is ignored by wcf though, the message is clearly buffered.
- It seems to be a missing feature, according to [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/366324/support-non-chunked-streamed-responses-on-wcf-httptransport#details). But there may still be a quirky workaround somewhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tested workaround, that only works for WCF under IIS - I have not found any solution for a self-hosted service.

In short - turn on [aspNetCompatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.aspnetcompatibilityenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which gives you runtime access to [System.Web.HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`Web.config`:

```
(...)
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
              <binding transferMode="Streamed">
              </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
(...)
</system.serviceModel>
```

and in your service function that returns a Stream:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", 
contentLength.ToString());
```

Anything like the following will be silently ignored:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Length"] = 
        contentLength.ToString();
```

Simple as that! Creds goes to [Uffe Lausen's question on Msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab695111-f3a8-4599-af16-4db26c70936d/how-do-i-set-contentlength-header-from-an-idataservicestreamprovider?forum=adodotnetdataservices)

Comment: Hi @Tewr, did you find a solution for self-hosted services?

Comment: I never did. Doesn't mean there is none - the project that drove me to writing this question got migrated to WebAPI about a year later. WebAPI does not have this problem. IMO as this is really only a problem when your client is a browser, WebAPI should be the go-to solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the control over the client code, you could write the data length as the first bytes in response stream, this is how i do it to transfer large files, but the client must know that the first bytes are only the size and not containing any data.

Example @server:

```
public Stream GetBigData()
{
    byte[] bigData = GetBigDataFromSomeWhere();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var lengthInfo = BitConverter.GetBytes(bigData.Length);
    ms.Write(lengthInfo, 0, lengthInfo.Length);
    ms.Write(bigData , 0, bigData .Length);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

Example @client:

```
using (var respStream = yourService.GetBigData())
using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //read first 4 bytes 
    var lengthBuffer = new byte[4];
    respStream.Read(lengthBuffer, 0, 4);
    var totalCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);
    resultStream.Capacity = totalCount;

    //read rest
    var readcount = 0;
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
    while ((readcount = respStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, readcount);
        UpdateProgress(readcount, totalCount)
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, as stated in the question (I'll emphasize this somewhat so that it's more clear), the client is a web browser. So any workaround on client-side would have to use javascript or any other browser-available trick. Although if someone answers "no" to my question, I may have to consider a custom downloader, which will probably look something like your answer.