# SVN: DAV request failed: 411 Content length required. http-chunked-requests

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, content-length, http-status-code-411

When I try to checkout project from SVN I got the following error

```
    RA layer request failed
svn: DAV request failed: 411 Content length required. The server or an intermediate proxy does not accept chunked encoding. Try setting 'http-chunked-requests' to 'auto' or 'no' in your client configuration.
```

I have searched so many forums they said that issue has been resolved but I am still facing the issue and I am using following version of SVN Client.

Also in Eclipse I cannot download project, using tigris client also.

```
TortoiseSVN 1.8.6, Build 25419 - 64 Bit , 2014/04/12 11:40:48
Subversion 1.8.8, -release
apr 1.5.0
apr-util 1.5.3
serf 1.3.4
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
zlib 1.2.8
```

Please help me what to do? I cannot checkout project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chunked encoding and content-length header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304126/chunked-encoding-and-content-length-header)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This probably happens because your backend is an older svn version.

In your `~/.subversion/servers` file, make sure you have a section like this:

```
[global]
http-chunked-requests = no
```

Comment: Where is this file places? I have installed Eclipse Plugin

Comment: @AZ_ you can find it in TortoiseSVN "Settings"/"Network", click "Edit" button for "Subversion server file".