# http.StreamedResponse contentLength returns null

Tags: .htaccess, flutter, dart, webserver, cpanel

I am using flutter `http` https://pub.dev/packages/http package to download a file from my own webserver.

Below is the download function:

```
  download(String url, {String filename}) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var request = new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
    var response = client.send(request);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

    List<List<int>> chunks = new List();
    int downloaded = 0;

    response.asStream().listen((http.StreamedResponse r) {
      r.stream.listen((List<int> chunk) {
        // Display percentage of completion
        debugPrint('downloadPercentage: ${downloaded / r.contentLength * 100}');

        chunks.add(chunk);
        downloaded += chunk.length;
      }, onDone: () async {
        // Display percentage of completion
        debugPrint('downloadPercentage: ${downloaded / r.contentLength * 100}');

        // Save the file
        File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
        final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(r.contentLength);
        int offset = 0;
        for (List<int> chunk in chunks) {
          bytes.setRange(offset, offset + chunk.length, chunk);
          offset += chunk.length;
        }
        await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
        return;
      });
    });
  }
```

But `StreamedResponse` r is always `null` when I download the file from my webserver. I can download files from other web servers and it is not `null`.

For testing purpose, I used the link https://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar590.exe

Therefore, I think the problem might be because of the settings on my webserver.

From WinRAR server

```
I/flutter (18386): IOStreamedResponse
I/flutter (18386): ResponseCode: 200
I/flutter (18386): {last-modified: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 10:03:25 GMT, date: Mon, 04 May 2020 11:47:34 GMT, accept-ranges: bytes, strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000;, content-length: 3007728, etag: "2de4f0-5a1bf18799540", content-type: application/octet-stream, server: Apache}
```

From my webserver:

```
I/flutter (29858): IOStreamedResponse
I/flutter (29858): ResponseCode: 200
I/flutter (29858): {connection: keep-alive, last-modified: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 20:22:20 GMT, set-cookie: __cfduid=d2789e7dce3f93d32c76e1d7874ffce1b1588599373; expires=Wed, 03-Jun-20 13:36:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.devoup.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax, cf-request-id: 02817fd5a30000ddc752a1d200000001, transfer-encoding: chunked, date: Mon, 04 May 2020 13:36:13 GMT, access-control-allow-origin: *, vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, content-encoding: gzip, cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC, content-type: application/zip, server: cloudflare, accept-ranges: bytes, cf-ray: 58e29c029952ddc7-SIN}
```

Comment: what do you need `response.asStream().listen` for? you have `var response = client.send(request);` - here `var response` is `Future<StreamedResponse>` so simply await that `Future` to get `StreamedResponse`

Comment: @pskink because I want to show the download percentage.

Comment: `var response = await client.send(request);
print(response.runtimeType);
print(response.statusCode);
print(response.headers);
response.stream.listen((data) { 
  print('chunk: ${data.length}');
});` what you see if you use this?

Comment: so as you can see you dont need `response.asStream().listen(...)` at all

Comment: @pskink status code is `404`. when I use your code, it only prints the first chunk received. I want also to get the filesize to the download file. In that way only I can show progress.

Comment: @pskink I have updated my question. Check the `response` & `headers` I get from both web servers when I made the request to download file

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: so what is the output of `curl -IL http://<your_uri>` command? also what you see if you replace `print('chunk: ${data.length}');` with `print(utf8.decode(data));`?

Comment: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x36 (at offset 11)` when I use `print(utf8.decode(data));`

Comment: also, status code returns `200`. I made a mistake in the uri

Comment: so you have 200, 200 is normal ok status, the code simply works

Comment: Now I only need to find the total size of the file. What I noticed is that `header` is not returning `content-length: xxx`

Comment: how to I make sure the header returns `content-length`? is it a setting from my webserver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304126/chunked-encoding-and-content-length-header

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added `SetEnv no-gzip 1` to `.htaccess` file and now it returns `content-length`. Also, as you suggested I modified the code without `response.asStream().listen` works perfectly. Can you add as an answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `SetEnv no-gzip 1` to `.htaccess` file in webserver and it returns `content-length`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the server doesn’t return contentLength . If that’s the case, then contentLength will be null.

If you have control of the server, like in your case, you can set the x-decompressed-content-length header with the file size before you send it. On the client side, you can retrieve contentLength like this:

```
final contentLength = double.parse(response.headers['x-decompressed-content-length']);
```

If you don't have control of the server, you can just show the number of bytes that are being downloaded, or if you know the file size in advance, you can use it to help calculate the % number of bytes downloaded.