# uWSGI. How to delete Content-Length header if Transfer-Encoding: chunked added?

Tags: uwsgi

API always server return `Content-Length` header, I add response compression to the `uWSGI` and want to follow [RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304186/4249707). My try:
`uwsgi.ini`

```
http-keepalive = 1

response-route-if = contains:${HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING};gzip goto:compress
response-route-run = last:

response-route-label = compress
response-route-run = delheader:Content-Length
response-route-run = gzip:
response-route-run = chunked:
```

uWSGI 2.0.19.1

Result: `Content-Length` still here.
Expected result: `Content-Length` header deleted from response headers.